# facebook ads daily stats change after collection

Tags: facebook, api, statistics, ads, facebook-ads-api

I'm writing service which is gathering facebook ads statistics on the daily basis.
The problem is that my collected stats mismatch facebook stats for the particular time period in the past.

For example:

- my ad account time zone is UTC+2 and today is 2012-12-18
- at 2012-12-18T00:00:00 UTC my service did request to ads api - ..../stats/2012-12-17T02:00:00/2012-12-18T02:00:00 
  to get daily statistics for 2012-12-17. The result was (for particular adgroup, truncated): impressions = 14950, clicks = 78, etc...
- at 2012-12-18T10:52:00 i did same request to fb ads api manually ..../stats/2012-12-17T02:00:00/2012-12-18T02:00:00, 
  expecting api results will match results in my database, but they are not! Api result was (for same adgroup, truncated): impressions = 15754, clicks = 82, etc...

So it looks like fb ads stats changed, after it was collected. My service includes utc time zone offsets, as suggested in api docs, 
and i expected 100% match of collected and actual stats, on daily basis.

Does anybody meet same issue?

Answer (score 0):

We've had the same problem in our accounts.

It's a timezone related issue, you should adjust the timezone, mainly with DST.

You can check the potential dates with problems depending the account timezone here: http://www.timeanddate.com/time/dst/2013.html
and adjust the time offset in the request with the new the start_time and end_time.

A better approach is to automate these changes using timezonedb to keep track of these adjustments to be done: http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/TZ_Database

hope it helps!

regards,
Martin